# ¿Como puedo hacer un try catch y que me repita la opcion que estoy haciendo?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Ingrese tipo de cuenta  \n1. corriente\n2.Ahorro");
tipo=Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());//-->>
```

¿Cómo podria hacer que por ejemplo aqui tiene que ingresar un numero pero si al momento de ingresar lo hace con una letra se que el `try` `catch` seria el de `Numberformat` pero para que repita ingresar la opcion como podria hacerlo??

Comment: seria mejor con un ciclo, en el cual valides que sea un letra

Comment: Deberías hacer lo que te dice @srJJ, un bucle y dentro del bucle el try catch para controlar que lo que te pasen sea un número.

Answer (score 1):

leyendo lo que necesitas he implementado un ciclo con un `try catch` en el cual lo hara hasta que sea un numero.

```
boolean resultado;
int tipo;
 do
 {

   System.out.println("Ingrese tipo de cuenta  \n1. corriente\n2.Ahorro");

   try {
            tipo=Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
            resultado = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException excepcion) {
            resultado = false;
        }
 }
 while (!resultado);
```

espero te sirve y la marques xD... ReNiceCode...